# How can I use a keydown event in a group?

Tags: javascript, konvajs

I'm working on a group formed with rects and transformers, now there's a need to move it in ways other than the mouse. Using containers I can move it using the arrow keys but with the group the Keydown function does not work, I already tried using group.on without success.

I would like that when clicking the arrows would start to work in the group moving it.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please update your question with the desired behavior, specific problems, and code to reproduce it. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't listen to keyboard event on canvas nodes (such as `Group` or `Shape`) with `Konva`. But you can easily emulate it.

You can make `Stage` node focusable and listen to keyboard events on it. Then do required action in an event handler.

```
   var container = stage.container();

    // make it focusable

    container.tabIndex = 1;
    // focus it
    // also stage will be in focus on its click
    container.focus();


    const DELTA = 4;

    container.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
      if (e.keyCode === 37) {
        circle.x(circle.x() - DELTA);
      } else if (e.keyCode === 38) {
        circle.y(circle.y() - DELTA);
      } else if (e.keyCode === 39) {
        circle.x(circle.x() + DELTA);
      } else if (e.keyCode === 40) {
        circle.y(circle.y() + DELTA);
      } else {
        return;
      }
      e.preventDefault();
      layer.batchDraw();
    });
```

Demo: https://konvajs.org/docs/events/Keyboard_Events.htm